# how to define a scenario in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

my model rules are like this

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['email','password'], 'required'],
                [['email'],'unique'],
                [['status','role_id','created_by', 'updated_by', 'is_deleted'], 'integer'],
                [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
                [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username','location','address','about_me'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
                [['phone'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
            ];
        }
```

while creating a new user i need email and password required, but during update i need only username required. how can i do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, it's better to add scenarios as constants to model instead of hardcoded strings, for example:

```
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[['email','password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE],
```

Another way is to describe it in `scenarios()` method:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['email', 'password'];

    return $scenarios;
}
```

That way you need to specify all safe attributes for each scenario.

Finally, don't forget to set needed scenario after creating new model instance.

```
$model = new User;
$model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CREATE;
...
```

**Official docs:**

- [Scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios)