# Yii2: scenarios() model method

Tags: php, yii2, yii-validation

There are 2 needed functions: set password when registering and change password, if user forgot it. When user signs up, password length must be at least 4 chars; when changes pass - at least 5 chars.

View is common for registration and changing pass. Obviously, also 2 actions exist, in which either scenario 'signup', either 'change' used.
Code snippet in model:

```
public function rules() {
     return [
       ['password', 'string', 'min' => 4, 'on' => 'signup'],
       ['password', 'string', 'min' => 5, 'on' => 'change'],
     ];
}
```

But I want to do do it via *scenarios()*. How to do it? I'm a beginner in Yii, so did not understand, when and how to use *scenarios()*. Thanks.

**UPD**. I need to use *scenarios()* for **ONE** field with **ONE** rule, but **DIFFERENT** arguments to this one rule. [how to define a scenario in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112079/how-to-define-a-scenario-in-yii2) - it is NOT my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to define a scenario in Yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112079/how-to-define-a-scenario-in-yii2)

Comment: @Tony, no and no! I understand, how to use _scenarios()_ for _required_ validation. But in my situation pass is reqiured in both cases. I need to use scenarios() for ONE field with ONE rule, but DIFFERENT arguments to this one rule.

Comment: @Tony, sorry, it seems, I deleted your comment accidentally.
I tried, but behaviour of code becomes incorrect. I just need example, u see?
If I write, as u said: _$scenarios['signup'] = ['password'];_ and _$scenarios['signin'] = ['password'];_, how my _rules()_ method need to be changed? As I understand, I have to delete _on_ when using _scenarios()_. But it will not be correct. Otherwise, if I don’t need to change _rules()_, what sense to write _scenarios()_? It works great without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [documentation about `scenarios()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#scenarios%28%29-detail) says: *The default implementation of this method will return all scenarios found in the rules() declaration.* So generally you do not need to override this method, because it will look for `on` array keys to set active attributes for current scenario an validate them properly.

So in your case `'on' => 'some scenario'` for different validations of the same attribute is exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks a lot!
I think, I begin to understand diff between _on_ and _scenario()_ using. The 1st  used, if we need to apply the scenario for concrete **rule**:
`['password', 'required', 'on' => 'register']
 ['password', 'integer', 'on' => 'another_scenario']
`
And _scenario()_ used, if we need to apply the scenario for concrete **attribute**:
`public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios['signin'] = 'password';  //ALL rules will apply to pass field, when using ‘signin’ scenario
        return $scenarios;
    }`
Am I right in my assumptions?

Comment: @Boolean_Type: absolutely, that's correct (though you'd do `$scenarios['signin'] = ['password'];`, i.e. use an array of attributes which are set and validated in that scenario).